# Looking for participants for a lo-fi prototype unmoderated usability study

Tags: usability, usability-testing, usability-study

I'm currently learning and working on a portfolio project, i got a task to do an unmoderated usability study (low fidelity prototype). Would anyone be willing to help me by participating?
The project is a trailer watching app for a fictional movie theatre. There would be 4 usability tasks to complete (i'm guessing it would take up to 10min). I would send a link to figma prototype and the prompts, participants would record their screen and voice/commentary as completing the tasks, fill in SUS afterwards and then send the recording to me. The recording itself would only be seen by me (i would use it to fill in the notes spread-sheet that will be evaluated by my peers in the course).
Would really appreciate the help! Thank you :)

Comment: We can only answer specific questions, user testing is out of the scope of this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet would be to recruit users from platforms that are dedicated for this. Usability hub comes to mind (https://usabilityhub.com/).

Let me know if it helps.